# C inline all functions in source file

Tags: c, inline

In my project I have some "Interface" functions which are defined in my header files. But I have much more functions which are only used internally in the same source file. So there is also no function declaration in any header file.

Is it good practice to declare them as `inline`? Since inline functions are better in performance it sounds like a good idea to me. Or are there any drawbacks? I know that the executable file might get larger in size but this is ok for me.

Comment: Is good practice to declare them as `static`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Local functions, not shared in different units of translations, should be qualified as `static`.
The `inline` specifier instructs compiler to inline the function if it can, but doesn't impose the inlining. If you require that the compiler inlines the function use `forceinline`, or `__forceinline`, to force the inlining.
Anyway when inlining functions consider that this is not always the best solution. You should carefully check the overall performance of your code. The inlining process merge the code of the function inside the calling code. This requires some register availability to perform calculation without disturbing the main execution. Sometime the process of register scooting requires temporary storage of current values or the like that could deteriorate the overall efficiency of code.
The inlining is beneficial when it is a short process and the time required for its execution inside main code is less than the time required for call prologue and epilogue.

Answer (score 3):

Don't hesitate, just tag them as `static inline` as you want.

Note that a function marked `inline` is **not necessary** inline. It's left to the compilers to judge whether to make it inline. Modern compilers are "clever" enough, so simply let your compiler make its decision, which is trustworthy.

Answer (score 3):

`inline` is just a hint to the compiler. If you specify `inline` the compiler may choose to not honour that hint. If you do not specify `inline` the compiler may choose to inline the function.

See [6.7.4 (p6) in the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.4).

Comment: So does it actually make a difference if I specify `inline` or not?

Comment: @ThomasSparber You give the compiler a suggestion by adding `inline`. Without that suggestion, a function won't be made inline.